# Barebonds Hello World Example with Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow-2

I am trying to setup a Barebonds Hello World Example with Security.  But I keep getting a error.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>MyFlow</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-config.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
</filter-class>
</filter>
</web-app>
```

Here is my spring-security.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http>
        <security:form-login />
        <security:http-basic />
        <security:logout />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_MEMBER" />
    </security:http>

    <security:user-service id="userService">
        <security:user name="habuma" password="letmein"
            authorities="ROLE_MEMBER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:user name="twoqubed" password="longhorns"
            authorities="ROLE_MEMEBER" />
        <security:user name="admin" password="admin"
            authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    </security:user-service>
</beans>
```

Below is my error.... please help me out:

> 2012-07-25 15:54:46,607 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' is defined: Did you forget to add a gobal  element to your configuration (with child  elements)? Alternatively you can use the authentication-manager-ref attribute on your  and  elements.
>
> at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have missed authentication-manager declaration ([see spring security docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-minimal))

```
    <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userService" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
```